# return value from mariadb in function nodejs

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mariadb

It's my code:

```
const mariadb = require('mariadb');
var test = async function(){
  var ret = "";
  await mariadb.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "dave",
        connectionLimit: 5,
        password: "!@#",
        database: "db",
        rowsAsArray: false
  }).then((data)=>{
    ret = "test";
  });
  return ret;
}

console.log(test());
```

How can I get a return from then using await?

I know that similar questions have been raised in many cases, but I could not find any using mariadb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already I can see a few pitfalls, which as beginners you will come across in this code:

- `avait` is waiting for results to be returned, as he will get `Promisses` to solve it
- `then` solves promises asynchronously
- function defined as `async` always returns promises

After a moment of delight, 'async / await' now I try to avoid him. Mainly because every function in which I use the asynchronous function must also be asynchronous until you use `then`, eg make small test:

```
  let test = async function() {
    let x = await 11
    return 1;
  }
  console.log(test()) //returns: Promise { <pending> }
```

There is nothing asynchronous there, but adding `async / await` has caused a mess.

Now fixes for your code

```
const mariadb = require('mariadb');
// use local scope `let` instead global `var`
let test = async function(){
  let conn = await mariadb.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "dave",
        connectionLimit: 5,
        password: "!@#",
        database: "db",
        rowsAsArray: false
  });
  return conn.query("SELECT 1 as val") // no sense using `avait` because `test()` returns `promise`
}

test().then(function(rows) { console.log(rows)});
```

and without asnc. `then` can return promise and this can be resolbed by next `then`

```js
mariadb.createConnection(...).then(conn => { // create connection
    return conn.query("SELECT 1 as val") // make query
}).then(rows => { //get result
    console.log(rows)
}).catch(err => console.error(err)) // get errors
```

By the way: get interested in query builder, for example knex.js. It allow write code independent from database engine.

#### Update

Let's start with the fact that Node is based on events.

Let's take an example of receiving data from the database. In PHP / C ++, you make an query, wait, receive a result. And this behavior simulates by the `await`. (Await appeared somewhere near version 8)

Normally, the code in the Node works so that you execute the query, and Node creates a new thread. Old run next instruction, in new  you will get the results. (OK, I'm lying, but it's easier to explain).

So, you have to handle the event of receiving the data. And more specifically the `promise` of providing data. By `await`,`.then ()`, or`callback (hell)`

#### first code explanation:

You try return `ret`, but this code first make `return ret` and after make assigment.

`await` "returns" data, so you should use `let var_name = await asyncFunction()`

I'm guess, that you want this:

```
let getSomeDataFromDB = function(){
  return mariadb.createConnection([skip]).then(conn => {
    return conn.query("SELECT 1 as val") 
  })
}
let rows = await getSomeDataFromDB()
```

In this function you return promise, who return promise. And by `await` this promise chain is resolved.

But here is a "small" error in the code. Because you are connecting and you are not ending your connection anywhere. Therefore, it is better to have a global connection object, or use something like this:

```
let getSomeDataFromDB = function(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    mariadb.createConnection([skip]).then(conn => {
      conn.query("SELECT 1 as val")
        .then(rows=>resolve(rows))
        .catch(e=>reject(e))
        .then(()=>conn.close())
    }).catch(e => reject(e))
  })
}
let rows = await getSomeDataFromDB()
```

And here you discover another important thing: `resolve` does not interrupt the execution of the code. Despite the data being returned to the user, you can still do something.

Or the same with `await`

```
let getSomeDataFromDB = async function(){
  let conn = await reateConnection([skip])
  let rows = await conn.query("SELECT 1 as val")
  await conn.close();
  return rows;
}
let rows = await getSomeDataFromDB()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the above solutions will fix my code because I have quite nested functions. I will try to rebuild the whole code of the main application engine, but thank you very much for the explanation. Now I know how to catch it more or less.

If anyone knows any unusual solution from the above situation, I will be grateful.

Comment: @Dave You know, you asked a general question, then you have a general answer. It would be good to know, for example: what version of the node you must use. I hope that the updated answer slightly clarified. If not, paste a piece of code that you do not understand. If you're ping me, I'll try to explain what's going on there.